# How to handle multiple UPSERT conflict constraints separately in the same query?

Tags: postgresql

I have a `users` table that contains 2 unique keys: all emails have to be unique and all the user_ids.

basically I want to do something like:

```
insert into my_table (column1, ...) values (value1, ...)
on conflict (user_id) do update set ...
on conflict (email) do nothing
```

Comment: Unfortunately that's not possible

Comment: Design you table so that the user_id is generated on insert. Do not include it in the insert. Then the only way to duplicate is a system failure (normally by manual intervention), but either way must be corrected before normal operation resumes. Then just worry about duplication on email.

Comment: It makes sense you’d think the user_id column is a serial generated on the table, but I’m using this column to store an id from another system, so the unique constraint is so that the same imported entry doesn’t get imported twice.  The email constraint is because the other system that I need to use the data from this table for does not accept duplicated emails.